# Calculate sum of textarea entries in an invoice

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea, invoice

I'm getting close with this, I'm just having trouble getting my first entry and second entry etc to add together.

My first entry shows up in the text field, and my second entry does as well, but they don't add together, it just shows the total, subtotal and tax of my second entry at the bottom, not the sum of the first and second entry.

Text area looks like this

```
<textarea input type ="text" name = "textarea" id = "textarea" rows = "12" cols = "180" placeholder = "--Item Code--  --Item Name--   --Item Cost-- --Quantity--  --Subtotal--  --Tax--  --Total--"></textarea>
```

My `document.getElementById` looks like this

```
    document.getElementById('textarea').value += ("\n")+("\n") + "--" + code + "--" + " " + " " + "--Item Name--" + "--" +  itemName + "--" + " " + " " + "--" + cost +"--" + " " + " " + "--" + quantity + "--" + " " + " " + "--" + subtotal + "--" + " " + " " + " " + "--" + tax + "--" + " " + " " + "--" + total + "--";
```

So every time I hit my Add Item button, it'll keep adding my entries to the text field, but it won't add the sum of all those entries.

I won't post my whole code, but I'll give a snippet to give you an idea

```
var subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal").value;
                 subtotal = cost * quantity; // multiplying cost by quantity = subtotal

            var tax = document.getElementById("tax").value;
                 tax = subtotal * .07; // multiplying subtotal by tax(.7) = amount of tax owed

            var total = document.getElementById("total").value;
                 total = tax + subtotal; //adding tax to subtotal = total value



            document.getElementById("subtotal").value = subtotal;

            document.getElementById("tax").value = tax;

            document.getElementById("total").value = total;
```

How can I get the sum of all my entries?  If you need me to post more code, I will.  I just wanted to keep this post concise and to the point. .

EDIT:

I'm making an invoice, and the user enters

Below shows the layout of the page

Item Code (text field for user to enter info)
Item Name (text field for user to enter info)
Item Cost (text field for user to enter info)
Quantity  (text field for user to enter info)

(Big text area here where the user's entries go.  when I click add item for multiple entries, it shows what the user entered as a list.  so:
First entry = 3        Ipod         200          1
Second entry = 2       Tv           400          1 )   < --  This is the middle of the page (textarea)

Subtotal (calculated value)
Tax  (calculated value)
Total (calculated value)

I can calculate these fine for one value.  And it adds the entries in the textarea.  But my subtotal, tax and total field don't add the entries. (First entry + second entry etc)

So when I put in the second value at 400.  It doesn't add that to the subtotal, tax and total of the first entry, it replaces the first entry in the calculated value portion, and puts the second entry as if the first entry never existed.

However, the textarea shows the multiple user entries.

Comment: You are using a single textarea to hold multiple input values? Could you make a jsbin?

Comment: Yeah.  I have a total, subtotal and tax text field on the bottom, but in the middle of the page there's a textarea to show the user's entries.   I think I need to clarify my post.

Comment: I have a feeling you're just going to need to split the string by a space like...  valueOfInput = docuemnt.getElementById('inputs').value; valueOfInput = valueOfInput.split(' '); then run a for loop on the array.  If you can get a working bin of an input field that you are trying to use with sample values, it'd be easy to write it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var inputVal = $('textarea').val();
inputVal = inputVal.split('\n');

var total = 0;

for (var i = inputVal.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(inputVal[i] === ''){
        continue;
    }
    var values = inputVal[i].split(' ');
    total += parseInt(values[0],10) * parseInt(values[2],10);

};
```